# Diffeomorphisms pushing forward vector field to any non-zero multiple

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, differential-topology

Is there a closed smooth manifold $M$ such that for each real $x\neq 0$ there is a nowhere vanishing vector field $v$ on $M$ and a diffeomorphism $\phi:M\to M$ such that $\phi_*v=xv$?

Comment: Do you want $v$ to be non-vanishing everywhere? Otherwise you can take $M$ to be the Riemann sphere $\mathbb{C} \cup \{\infty\}$, $v$ to be a multiple of the radial vector field vanishing at $0$ and $\infty$, and the diffeomorphism $\phi$ to just be multiplication by a real number $\lambda > 0$. To get negative constants, I believe you can just compose this with $z \mapsto z^{-1}$.

Comment: @RohilPrasad yes, thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Such a manifold exists. First let's construct a non-compact example.

Take $PSL(2,\mathbb R)$ and take two $1$-parameter subgroups,  given by $$\begin{pmatrix}
e^{t} & 0 \\
0 & e^{-t} 
\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}
1 & t \\
0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}$$
Consider actions on $PSL(2,\mathbb R)$ of these two groups by multiplication on the left. Then $v$ is the vector field tangent to the second flow, while the first flow will give you a $1$-parameter family of diffeos that will dilate $v$ by any positive constant.

Now, to get the compact example, quotient $PSL(2,\mathbb R)$ from the right by a cocompact action of the fundamental group $\Gamma$ of a compact hyperbolic surface.

It remains to understand how to reverse the sign of $v$. For this recall, that we can identify $PSL(2,\mathbb R)/\Gamma$ with the unit tangent bundle of a hyperbolic surface (whose $\pi_1$ is equal to $\Gamma$). Now, the flow given by $v$ is the horocyclic flow. In order to reverse it, we can take a hyperbolic surface that admits and orientation reversing isometric involution. Such an involution clearly lifts to the unit tangent bundle and it sends the horocyclic flow to its inverse.